# How to call non-class method from static class method in Javascriopt

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want a non-class method to be executed whenever the static class method is called.
This static class method will be called from some other program present in some other directory, every 10 seconds.
The non-class method will call the python script by spawning.

I have done this by calling a non-class method from a static class method. 
I want to know whether the way I am doing this is right or not. Or Is there some other good way.

home/sampath/file1/program1.js

```
class A {
 constructor (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
 }

 static updateDate (name, age) {
  let obj = new A (name, age);
  callFunc (obj);
 }
}

function callFunc (obj) {
 //calls python script with the given object as agrument;
 //argument obj.name, obj.age
}

module.exports = A;
```

home/sampath/file2/program2.js

```
const A = require ('../file1/program1');

//This statement is executed every 10 seconds.
A.updateData ('some_name', 'some_age');
```

Everything is working now. But I want to know the way I am doing this is correct or not.

Comment: If by "*non-class method*" you mean `callFunc`, that's just a plain *function* not a *method*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If it is working, then it is by definition correct. Are you asking us whether this solution is *appropriate* for your problem, whether it is a *good solution*? Then you need to tell us what problem you were solving. Yes, it's fine to call non-class functions from class methods (static or not), but what was your reason to do that? Alternatives would be doing the python call right inside `updateData` - since nothing else calls `callFunc`, or making `callFunc` a method of the `A` instance.